# Continuous function preserves the immediate basin of attraction?

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems, basins-of-attraction

Suppose that $f$ is a differentiable function and $p$ is a fixed point of $f$ such that $|f′(p)|<1$.

Let $K$ be the maximal interval about $p$ in which all points tend asymptotically to $p$ under $f$, i.e., K is the connected component of $\{x :f^n(x) \to p$ as $n \to \infty\}$ which contains p. $K$ is known as the immediate basin of attraction of $p$.

How to prove that $f(K) \subset K$?

ps. $f^n$ is the n-time composition of $f$ whit itself

Comment: Is $f_n(x)$ the $n$-time composition of $f$ with itself? Then trivially $f_n(f(x))= f_{n+1}(x) \to p$.

Comment: Yes, $f_n$ the n-time composition of f with itself. The usual notation is $f^n$. Was a typo, but okay.
If  $B = \{ x : f^n(x) \to p$ as $ n \to \infty \}$, then your argument shows that $f(x) \in B$ when $x \in B$. I agree. But, specifically, why $f(x) \in K$ when $x \in K$. Seems clear, but I can't see it.